# Similar Function to CONTAINS

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hello I am looking for a function that is similar to the [CONTAINS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx) function however, it does not require the field to be full-text indexed. Basically I have a field which contains some codes delimited by a space like so `ABC DEF GHI`. I want to run a query and to see if `DEF` is in the field. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: LIKE '%DEF%' would work, but it can be sloooooooooooooooooooowwwwwww. "A field which contains some codes delimited by a space" should be avoided.

Comment: @aehiilrs I know but unfortunately that is the way the database was setup and I can not change it so I will have to make do! :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [CHARINDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx). Note that I've added a space to the beginning and end of the column being searched to account for the case where your search string is first or last in the list.

```
SELECT *
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE CHARINDEX(' DEF ', ' ' + YourColumn + ' ') <> 0;
```

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like you might want the `LIKE` operator. Query would look something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM someTable WHERE someField LIKE '%DEF%'
```

Comment: The column is a space delimited collection of values. This would yield false results if the column contained, for example, 'ABC 12DEF34 GHI'. You're not accounting for the space delimiters in your search.

Answer (score 2):

```
WHERE YourField like '% DEF %' 
OR YourField LIKE '% DEF'
OR yourField like 'DEF %' 
OR YourField = 'DEF'
```

Covers the case of it being in the middle surrounded by spaces, or at the end / start - and final edge case of the statement only being that value with no spaces. Deliberately used / ensured spaces in case you have a value of 'ADEFB', e.g. one code inside another.

Performance will not be great.